# How to use DeepLink in navigation component in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my application I have **NavigationComponent** and I want set **DeepLink** for this. 
My deep link is : **app://myapp.com**

I write below codes, but after click on url not suggest my application!
I want when click on link, suggest my application.

**my navigation code:**

```
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/myFragment"
            android:name="MyFragment"
            android:label="fragment_my"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_my">
            <deepLink
                android:id="@+id/deepLink"
                app:uri="app://myapp.com" />
        </fragment>
```

**Manifest code:**

```
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <nav-graph android:value="@navigation/nav_main" />
        </activity>
```

How can I fix this problem ?